# Mi computadora no se apaga con ninguna distro de linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo Ubuntu 16.04 en mi Aspire ES1-512 pero cuando quiero reiniciar o apagra mi computadora no se apaga por completo, solo aparecen los puntos de carga debajo de "Ubuntu" pero se congela la pantalla, por lo cual debo usar el boton de apagado, esto mismo me paso con Fedora, Debian y Kali. Hay forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Esta pregunta no corresponde a un error de programacion, busca soporte en otras fuentes de stack o en buscadores, voto por cerrar

Comment: Si haz solucionado tu problema podrías poner como solucionado. Gracias

Comment: Tip: investiga si tu equipo usa el modulo ACPI correcto. Con frecuencia ese es el módulo del kernel que impide el correcto apagado/hibernación/suspensión correcta.

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso has la siguiente prueba para ver que pasa.
1: Abre un terminal y escribe el siguiente comando(SOlo te servirá para basados en debian)

**sudo shutdown -h now**

revisa si el equipo se apaga, si es asi yo te recomiendo que entonces te crees un Script en bash con el comando que te di y cuando quieras apagar el equipos lo ejecutar.

Answer (score 1):

Para apagar Ubuntu podrías probar con:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

o

```
sudo poweroff
```

En caso que quisieras reiniciar:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

o

```
sudo reboot
```